# Thumbor decode url error KeyError: 'Body'

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, thumbor

Hi guy i have problem with laravel thumbor

```
2023-10-13 11:45:28 2023-10-13 04:45:28 botocore.credentials:INFO Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2023-10-13 11:45:29 2023-10-13 04:45:29 thumbor:ERROR ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thumbor/handlers/__init__.py", line 153, in get_image
2023-10-13 11:45:29     self.context.request.image_url
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
2023-10-13 11:45:29     value = future.result()
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
2023-10-13 11:45:29     raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
2023-10-13 11:45:29     yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thumbor/handlers/__init__.py", line 576, in _fetch
2023-10-13 11:45:29     fetch_result.buffer = yield gen.maybe_future(storage.get(url))
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
2023-10-13 11:45:29     value = future.result()
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
2023-10-13 11:45:29     raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 316, in wrapped
2023-10-13 11:45:29     ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 497, in run_callback
2023-10-13 11:45:29     callback(future.result())
2023-10-13 11:45:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tc_aws/storages/s3_storage.py", line 63, in parse_body
2023-10-13 11:45:29     callback(key['Body'].read())
2023-10-13 11:45:29 KeyError: 'Body'
2023-10-13 11:45:29 
2023-10-13 11:45:29 2023-10-13 04:45:29 thumbor:ERROR [BaseHandler] get_image failed for url `users/6354/userProfile_169716934`. error: `'Body'`
2023-10-13 11:45:29 2023-10-13 04:45:29 tornado.access:ERROR 500 GET /hjLSq4yvE7CEWff-OH7t17eTkkI=/164x164/filters:watermark(/watermark/watermark.png,-10,-10,0,30,30)/users/6354/userProfile_1697169341.webp (172.26.0.1) 872.03ms
```

this my error
on this line `thumbor:ERROR [BaseHandler] get_image failed for url users/6354/userProfile_169716934. error: 'Body'`

I found URL not some string missing? correct URL is `users/6354/userProfile_1697169341.webp`

i don't know what happened nobody touch it